# Div position at the center

Tags: html, css-float, css-position

below is my code

```
    <div class="center" style="text-align:center;">     
    <div style="position:relative;width:26%;min-width:300px;float:left;background-color:red;border:1px solid black;"">  
    <img width=500px;height=500px; src="<?php echo $this->basePath().'/images/feat/shop/5/5_large.jpg';?>">
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;min-width:100px;width:10%;height:500px;background-color:green;border:1px solid black;"">   
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative;width:26%;float:left;min-width:300px;background-color:blue;border:1px solid black;">  
    <img width=500px;height=500px; src="<?php echo $this->basePath().'/images/feat/shop/5/5_large.jpg';?>">
    </div>
    </div>
```

above div with class `center` is position `left` side but i want to position it exactly at the center of the screen without using `Margin` , `padding` ,`left` `right`  properties,as you can see i have already tried using 'text-align' but did not work,  is it possible?

Comment: please avoid inline styles.

Comment: ya just for testing i have put inline style, once the isue been resolved , i gonna use external style sheet

Comment: What is your problem with margin? :o

Comment: when i reduce the browser width size to the least possible, then the div should move to the left , but if we use margin, it takes margin width so it does not move to left compleatly..,,,

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
<div class="center" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;">     
...
```

Or to make it more accurate try using the `calc()` function:

```
<div class="center" style="position: absolute; top: calc(100%/2 - divHeight/2); left: calc(100%/2 - divWidth/2);">     
....
```

According to you, you are not using `margin` because when you will reduce your window size to the least possible the div will not move to the left. Well here is my answer, using `margin` with `pixels` do what you are concerened of but using `margin` with `percentage(%)` will help you achieving what you want.

**Using percents:**
Using percents is not that hard but the unit is different from pixels. If you want your div to be in the center.

Try doing this:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Or this:

```
margin: 0 calc(50% - divWidth/2);
```

That will surely help you in achieving what you want.

Hope it helped.

Comment: thanks for your reply @
Mohammad Areeb Siddiqui  but iam triing to do it without using `left`, `top`  properties

Comment: @Friend you talked about `margin` and `padding` so that's why.